# How to create self cumulating vector in R

Tags: r

I think this is very easy but my R kung-fu is weak. I'm trying to create a vector of itself in a cumulative way. This code works but I'd like something much more elegant and automated. I have millions of rows that need to be cumulated.

```
a <- c(4,4,5,1,9)
a <- a[order(-a[])]
k <- a[1:length(a)]/sum(a)
w <- c(k[1],k[1]+k[2],k[1]+k[2]+k[3],k[1]+k[2]+k[3]+k[4],k[1]+k[2]+k[3]+k[4]+k[5])
w
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean `cumsum()` ?

```
> a <- c(4,4,5,1,9)
> a <- a[order(-a[])]            # just calling sort is shorter too
> k <- a[1:length(a)]/sum(a)     # long way  
> k 
[1] 0.391304 0.217391 0.173913 0.173913 0.043478
> k <- a/sum(a)                  # same, but shorter
> k  
[1] 0.391304 0.217391 0.173913 0.173913 0.043478
> ck <- cumsum(k) 
> ck  
[1] 0.39130 0.60870 0.78261 0.95652 1.00000 
>
```

*Edit* I overlooked another simplification:

```
> a <- c(4,4,5,1,9)
> ck <- cumsum( sort(a, decr=TRUE) / sum(as) ) 
> ck  
[1] 0.39130 0.60870 0.78261 0.95652 1.00000 
>
```

You want `sort()` here rather than `order()` coupled with indexing.

Comment: Or `prop.table(cumsum(sort(a, decr=TRUE)))`

Answer (score -1):

Bing is my friend...I found the cumsum() function.

Comment: If bing is your fried, then [rseek.org](http://rseek.org) is bound to be your uncle...